# Export artwork from InDesign to MS-Word with print-quality

Tags: print-design, file-format, microsoft-word

Please help with advice, what is the best file format to export 1 page from InDesign and place it in MS-Word with high-quality (for print)?

That's should be 2-pages flier, where one of them should be complete 1 page from InDesign. (You'd better don't ask why :(

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Sorry.. I gotta ask, why? This is backwards, You should import from Word to InDesign then make a PDFx file from Indesign. Word is **not** now and has never been designed for high quality print production. In fact, many print providers will refuse Word files.

Comment: How do I upvote this like a hundred times.

Comment: Normally you should stick to experienced clients which have some basic knowledge of a print workflow. If you already promised this conversion, you're in for a surprise! :)

Comment: Its possible, but **very expensive** for your clients in terms of how much work and education they would need. I would only consider this after having done a interview to determine that the client understands the implications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part 1**

There is a contradiction between some concepts in your question.

Word vs. Print-Quality. We must define what is "print quality".

InDesign to Word, here is another contradiction.

So. "Print quality" as you are asking in a Graphic Design forum has very specific meanings, mainly, correct resolution, no visible compression, embedded color profiles, vector based texts, specific CMYK values corresponding to the color profile and some extra capabilities like defining overprint.

So all that goes to the drain when you embed something inside a Word document.

That is why the process normally is Word (used to write the content of a document) to InDesign (Used to shape that content and prepare it with print quality).

---

**Part 2**

But let me assume the thing you need is "good enough graphics" so people using Word can print in the office some elements designed in Indesign.

Simply export them as PNG with a resolution around 150ppi.

But you **can not** convert a template made in Indesign to Word.

You need to think in terms of Word, how it works, how it pushes elements or allow to wrap text around them.

So you make some visuals and insert them into Word, either using the Headers and Footers options of the document or inserting them as images and configuring the type of flow they need in the document.

And you need to define margins and columns with the tools Word has for them. And also you need to define the styles of the text using the correct tools.

Comment: I said high quality (as possible in this case), for print. Yes, that's for editable Word which could be printed on office printer when needed.
PNG-300ppi worked for me (150 ppi looks like not enough, and 600 ppi somehow looks worse then 300 ppi) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct conversion ID to Word. If only 2 pages, just create a new Word doc, copy text blocks  & graphics from ID, paste in Word, and clean up.

Sometimes clients require live Word files. Its a sad fact of life. Always offer a PDF instead! You might get lucky.

You can cheat, export a jpg from ID, and place it in Word. Don't laugh!

Comment: Who edited me to say "uneducated"? It might have nothing to do with education or ability, but with an MS Office-based workflow or IT infrastructure. It's wrong to assume that -only- "uneducated" clients need files in Word.

Comment: Some people, have a way of editing that changes what you are trying to say. It's very annoying and you can change the edit back if you please.

Comment: The same guy above says " you should stick to experienced clients." I'm just gonna let it lie there.

Comment: @q23.us if you disagree with the edit then edit yourself or rollback the edit

Comment: rolled back.. spelling errors corrected.

Answer (score 0):

There's a two-step method:
1. In InDesign, Export to PDF.
2. In Acrobat, open the PDF and Save As Other: Microsoft Word.
However, ID makes PDFs intended for printing or viewing (the raison d'etre of PDF), not for conversion to Word. You can expect some elements not to transfer properly. Be ready to do some cleanup in Word.
Over the years Acrobat has got better at #2, so you might get lucky.

Answer (score 0):

You can export an inDesign page to EPS format and then place the EPS directly into Word. The EPS will look like a low-resolution preview, but should print correctly.

If your inDesign document is full page, in Word you would want to set the image as "in front of" or "behind" text; set the size to 100%, locked aspect ratio; and set the horizontal and vertical position to "centered" relative to "page."

Comment: Thanks. I went with PNG (300 ppi).
Should EPS look good after export from Word in PDF? In my experience it doesn't (look a little distorted and blurry:(... That's also the case - need it good looking in PDF.